# Scala tuple manuplation

Tags: string, scala, tuples

I have a tuple like this

```
val numPairs = Set((2, "a"), (3, "b"), (20, "c"))
```

I want it's result to look like

```
(2, "a"), (3, "b"), (20, "c")
```

So I tried

```
println(numPairs.toString().replace("Set", ""))
```

but results are

```
(2, a), (3, b), (20, c)
```

And it is missing `""` for the string part of the tuple.

Can someone help please

Comment: Your first element is not a tuple is a sequence, and it is not clear what do you want as an output since multiple values can not exist on its own, or you simply want to format them as a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually format the string version of each tuple with some string interpolation, then join them with `mkString`

```
val numPairs = Set((2, "a"), (3, "b"), (20, "c"))

println(numPairs.map(a => s"""(${a._1}, "${a._2}")""").mkString(", "))
```

outputs

```
(2, "a"), (3, "b"), (20, "c")
```